Saving x265 udp stream to .mkv file
I am developing an KMP application, and as a part of it I need to record incoming udp stream to mkv file. My code works fine for x264 streams but for x265 streams it can't write header with "Invalid data found when processing input" error.
Here are some lines, where I'm setting params for encoder context and stream
        encoderContext.apply {
            gop_size(12)
            max_b_frames(3)
            framerate(frameRate)
            time_base(av_inv_q(frameRate))
            pix_fmt(AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P)
            width(width)
            height(height)

            val avFormatFlags = avOutputCtx?.oformat()?.flags() ?: 0
            if (avFormatFlags and AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER != 0)
                flags(flags() or AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER)

            profile(
                if (sourceConfig.encoding == SupportedEncoding.H264) FF_PROFILE_H264_MAIN
                else FF_PROFILE_HEVC_MAIN
            )

            if (codecId == AV_CODEC_ID_H265) {
                sample_aspect_ratio(av_make_q(16, 9))
                refs(3)
                bit_rate(20_000)

                av_opt_set(priv_data(), "profile", "high", 0)
                av_opt_set(priv_data(), "preset", "ultrafast", 0)
                av_opt_set(priv_data(), "crf", "35", 0)
                av_opt_set(priv_data(), "tune", "zerolatency", 0)
            }
        }

        outStream.apply {
            id(0)
            codecpar().codec_id(codecId)
            codecpar().codec_type(AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
            codecpar().format(AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P)
            codecpar().width(width)
            codecpar().height(height)
            time_base(av_inv_q(frameRate))
            codecpar().video_delay(0)
            avg_frame_rate(frameRate)

            val extraDataSize = 32
            val extraData = BytePointer(av_malloc(extraDataSize.toLong()))
            codecpar().extradata(extraData);
            codecpar().extradata_size(32)

            codecpar().codec_tag(0)
        }

